# Regarding fieldset tag and legend tag. Facing issue in the code

Tags: html, jsp, html-table, legend, fieldset

I have a fieldset tag and legend tag in one of my jsp page. Inside fieldset tag, I have a table. But when I run the page, the fieldset and legend tag is displaying above table. And when I inspect element in browser, fieldset tag is opened and closed above the table. I don't know why it is happening like that. Please check my code.

This is my actual code:

```
<fieldset><legend class="Headline">Ship To</legend></fieldset>
<table style="border:1px solid black;"width="100%"> <%--owais--%>

-----------
----------
--------

</table>
```

But when I inspect element in browser,
my code is different:

```
<fieldset><legend class="Headline">Ship To</legend>
<table style="border:1px solid black;"width="100%"> <%--owais--%>

-----------
----------
--------

</table>
<fieldset>
```

Comment: You have to press the "code sample {}" button to format code. I've done it for you. Please read the [help] pages to get the best from [SO].

Comment: Your "actual code" doesn't match the description of your code in the previous paragraph (and is invalid). The code the browser shows in the element inspector doesn't appear to be code that a browser *could* generate there. Try providing a real [mcve]